# Transform key-value pairs to a "ragged" list

Tags: r

I am looking for a generic way to transform a key-value pair data-frame into a "ragged" list.

```
key <- c("1","1","2")
val <- c("101","102","101")
x <- data.frame(key,val)
```

desired output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "101" "102"

[[2]]
[1] "101"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `split`

```
setNames(split(as.character(x$val), x$key), NULL)
#[[1]]
#[1] "101" "102"

#[[2]]
#[1] "101"
```

Or with `unstack`

```
unstack(x, as.character(val)~key)
```